# How to create and answer a logical problem from real life situation?

Tags: logic

> A colorblind mother has three kids: Pierre, Jacques and andré. as she know well her kids, she says the following:
>
> - I've at least a blond child
> - If Pierre is blond but André isn't, then Jacques is blond.
> - Jacques and andré have hair of the same color.
>
> What is the colour of the head of each child?

Let be P: Pierre has a blond hair, J: Jacques has a blond hair, A: André has a blond hair.

I know that it means that we have:

- $P\vee J\vee A$
- $(P\wedge \neg A) \rightarrow J$
- $J \wedge A$

Yet, when I compute it in a truth table I find two solutions,

$$\begin{array}{ccc|cccc}
P & J & A &\neg A & (P\wedge \neg A)& (P \wedge A )\rightarrow J & J \leftrightarrow A & P \vee J \vee A & the \ answer\\
\hline
T & T & T & F & F & T & T & T & T\\
T & F & T & F & F & T & F & T & F\\
F & T & T & F & F & T & T & T & F\\
F & F & T & F & F & T & F & T & T\\
T & T & F & T & T & T & F & T & F\\
T & F & F & T & T & F & F & T & F\\
F & T & F & T & F & T & F & T & F\\
F & F & F & T & F & T & F & T & F\\
\end{array}$$

As far as it seems in the text given that there is solely one solution, is my method good or did I missed something?
Furthermore, what should I write for "the answer" $(P \wedge A )\rightarrow J \wedge (J \wedge A) \wedge (P \vee J \vee A)$?

Comment: You haven't defined what $P,J,A$ mean. If it means the associated person has blonde hair, then you don't really know $J\land A$

Comment: ... but you do know that Jacques not blond and André blond does not satisfy them having the same colour hair

Comment: "Jacques and André have hair of the same color" is not $J\land A$, but rather $J\leftrightarrow A$. That is, Jacques has blond hair iff André has blond hair.

Comment: @Akiva Weinberger, Okay, what does it change in the truth table?

Comment: @Marine1 $J=F$ and $A=F$ works, since they're the same color (i.e. not blond). Symbolically, $F\leftrightarrow F$ is true.

Comment: "Jacques and andré have hair of the same color" means "Jacques is blonde if and only if André is", as @AkivaWeinberger says. That's the same thing as $(J \wedge A)  \vee  (\neg J \wedge \neg A)$. So your truth table changes accordingly. Note: we don't know about any other hair colors, the only two colors in question are "blonde" and "not-blonde".

Comment: So does it means I have two right answers? That doesn't seems logic (unless P,J and A are kind of Schrodinger cats ;) )

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. If Jacques and André are both blond, Pierre could be anything. I don't think you have enough information here.

Comment: That is, $(P,J,A)=(T,T,T)$ and $(P,J,A)=(F,T,T)$ both seem to work.

Comment: Yep, Pierre might be blonde, or not -- both are consistent. So mom still doesn't know Pierre's hair color.